# How to update common control in windows 2000 to version 6

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc

How can I update the common control dlls to version 6 on windows 2000.
I have built a MFC application using new features available in version 6 of windows common control. The default version of the dll in windows 2000 is 5.80. I need to support windows 2000, I am unable to find a way to update the common control dll. The Microsoft website mentions that common control version 6 in not redistributable.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already discovered, the common control library is not redistributable. So while you may technically be able to find a way to do this it will still not be legal. You will either have to remove the V6 features from your app, find an alternative third party supplier who can provide the same functionality, or write it yourself. Sorry if this isn't what you wanted to hear.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about it. Common Controls 6 is an XP+ feature. It involves manifests, which were introduced in XP.